# Links inside Sendgrid Emails Not Working After Pointing DNS domain to Linode servers

Tags: deployment, dns, sendgrid, linode, namecheap

(MERN PROJECT) I'm using Sendgrid to send emails to confirm user accounts once they register. Before hosting the app on Linode, the links inside the emails worked fine. After configuring my DNS (Namecheap) domain to point at Linode's servers the emails continued to function however the links inside of the emails became broken.

Clicking the link would produce this error: Check if there is a typo in url781.xxxxxx.com.

Before the configuration the links did not contain "url781" prefix and so everything worked fine.

Wondering if anyone has come across similar issues when working with an smtp provider during the deployment stage.

NOTE: I followed Linode's guide to setting MX servers and set up the Sendgrid configuration mentioned there but it did nothing to resolve this issue.